# Safely send many emails in PHP

Tags: php, email, spam

I'm building a website in PHP that allows users to send invitation emails. They are allowed to send more than one at once.

I'm told that using PHP's mail() function is a bad choice because it can easily be marked as spam. Is there some way that I can set up this script so that the emails are not marked as spam?

I've done quite a lot of reading and from what I've read today it seems like a few factors can influence whether mail is marked as spam including: the words used in the emails; the domain that the emails say they are sent from compared to where they actually originate; formatting of headers; and the frequency of emails sent.

The email addresses that we use are with Gmail Apps. So, if the emails I send don't "look" spammy, I send them from Gmail, and I can limit the frequency of the emails sent (maybe 10 every 10 minutes) then I should be able to do this without a problem right?

**EDIT**

This is not for a newsletter. Do I even have to worry about being marked as spam for invitation emails?

Comment: You have to be worried about being marked as spam for *any* bulk email. Your intent doesn't matter.

Comment: Yeah but I mean more like it's unlikely that someone will invite 500 friends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while your conclusion is correct, your reasoning is not quite right. php's mail function will not cause your emails to be marked as spam, because it sends the same emails as anything else would.

the problem with php's mail function is that it is very low level, and so if you do not know how to use it properly, and leave email injection vulnerabilities, people could use your site to send spam messages through it, and in turn this could get your server blacklisted as a source of spam by isps. as long as you strip \n and \r from your extra header fields (From:, etc), you should be safe.

Another issue is that you have to add your own valid headers to your emails.

Yet another issue is that it would connect and disconnect from your smtp server for each time you call mail(), although I think there is a way you can send multiple emails using one call to mail. this would be complicated though since it would probably involve looking through rfc282 and figuring out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

at first you need an valid mx.record for your domain...
if you use the mail function you should send valid headers like these:

```
function send_mail($from = FALSE,$to = FALSE, $msg = FALSE, $subject = FALSE, $html= TRUE){
    if($from && $to && $msg && $subject){
        if ($html){
            $header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n"; 
        }
            $header .= 'From: '.$from. "\r\n";          
            $header .= 'Reply-To: '.$from. "\r\n";
            $header .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            return mail ($to,$subject,$msg,$header);
    }
    return "fail";
}
```

Comment: MX records are with Gmail. So the only thing left is to make sure that I don't send out emails to frequently?

Comment: if you use a gmail account you need smpt like gabriel mentioned. its not only the frequency, its also the content. i wouldnt let send users any mails they want from my server.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a SMTP server and after that connect using any php library for php. Here you have some useful libraries and some examples as well

- http://phpmailer.worxware.com/
- http://swiftmailer.org/
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html

Comment: I'm leaning towards phpmailer, since I've heard that is good and reliable. My MX records are with Gmail, and I've checked (using the tools on phpmailer.worxware.com) that they aren't blacklisted and the DNS is good. So, the only thing I have to worry about is the frequency of sent emails?

Comment: actually you need to worry about the rate...Gmail has a daily cap: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=es&hlrm=en&answer=166852

Comment: (here the link above in english) http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=en&answer=166852